# Cannot Start Django in Docker

Tags: django, docker

I am trying to run Django-packages in Docker, but I am unable to.

I am getting the following:-

```
django_1    | Postgres is up - continuing...
django_1    | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
django_1    | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Everything seems to be fine though.The daemon is running.

**docker ps**

```
C:\djangopackages-master>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

**docker volume ls**

```
C:\djangopackages-master>docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               djangopackagesmaster_postgres_backup_dev
local               djangopackagesmaster_postgres_data_dev
local               ef5505952d82c1472e74e21a8d2921018b2f7ee5570742268c8560335fe5762b
```

Cant seem to figure  out what might be the issue.

**How i built the docker container:**
Ran **docker-compose -f dev.yml up** after cloning the following repo.
https://github.com/djangopackages/djangopackages

Docker Files present for creation:-

https://github.com/djangopackages/djangopackages/blob/master/compose/caddy/Dockerfile

https://github.com/djangopackages/djangopackages/blob/master/compose/django/Dockerfile

https://github.com/djangopackages/djangopackages/blob/master/compose/django/Dockerfile-dev

https://github.com/djangopackages/djangopackages/blob/master/compose/postgres/Dockerfile

https://github.com/djangopackages/djangopackages/blob/master/compose/redis/Dockerfile

**In this particular dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Requirements have to be pulled and installed here, otherwise caching won't work
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

COPY ./manage.py /manage.py

RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY ./compose/django/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

COPY ./compose/django/start-dev.sh /start-dev.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start-dev.sh
RUN chmod +x /start-dev.sh


WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

If I tell to copy manage.py as well then manage.py runs(with errors of course). It seems it is not running the manage.py in the correct path. not sure what to do here anymore.

Comment: Can you post your image file? Are you sure the tree your code is in is mounted in the docker container?

Comment: I am not sure about the path of the image file. Can you point to it?
The directory should be present I think.

Comment: The docker file used to build your container. Can you post that?

Comment: Added more info